# Apply a CSS selector on all removed nodes with MutationObserver HTML5 API

Tags: javascript, html, css, mutation-observers

Below is how I get **all removed nodes from the DOM that have a class in the list `selected_classes`**. It works but it's rather complicated (and some corner cases might be forgotten?).

Is there a more general way to filter removed nodes from the DOM *by CSS selectors*? Pseudo-code:

```
new MutationObserver(mut => {
    removed_nodes = removed_nodes(mut);
    console.log(removed_nodes.querySelectorAll('.hello'));
    console.log(removed_nodes.querySelectorAll('.myclass #a'));
}).observe(document.querySelector("html"), { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Here is the working code, only for classes:

```js
selected_classes = {"banana": 0, "hello": 0};

new MutationObserver(mut => {
    for (m of mut) {
        for (n of m.removedNodes) {
            if (n.classList)   // text node don't have a classList!
                for (c of n.classList.values())
                    if (c in selected_classes)
                        console.log("selected_classes found:", n);
            if (n.childNodes)
                for (n2 of n.childNodes.values())
                    if (n2.classList)
                        for (c of n2.classList.values())
                            if (c in selected_classes)
                                console.log("selected_classes found:", n2);                
        }
    }
}).observe(document.querySelector("html"), { childList: true, subtree: true });

document.getElementById("c").onclick = () => { document.getElementById("b").remove(); }
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b" class="tomato">b
<div id="b1">b1</div>
<div id="b2" class="hello">b2 (class hello)</div>
</div>
<div id="c">Click to remove b</div>
```

Comment: _"More generally is there a better way..."_ -> Asks for an [opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) unless you define in-depth what _"better"_ means. If you want others to rewrite your code -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: _"// text node don't have a classList!"_ - Nodes do have a `.nodeType` property...

Comment: @Andreas I removed this part of the question, in fact I'm looking for a general way (maybe already present in the API), the wording better was inappropriate indeed.

Comment: @Andreas Yes they have a `.nodeType`, we could use that but it's even easier to directly test if `classList` is there or not.

Comment: _"Is there a more general way"_ - A recursive function. Your function can only handle elements with children, but not children-of-children. Or just `n.matches(...)` / `n.querySelectorAll(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CSS selector from `selected_classes` and use that with `.matches()` and `.querySelectorAll()` to get matching notes

```js
const selector = ".banana, .hello";

new MutationObserver(mut => {
 
  for (m of mut) {
    for (n of m.removedNodes) {
      if (n.matches(selector)) {
        console.log("direct match", n);
      }

      n.querySelectorAll(selector)
         .forEach(c => console.log("child (any depth)", c));
    }
  }
}).observe(document.querySelector("html"), { childList: true, subtree: true });

document.getElementById("c").onclick = () => { document.getElementById("b").remove(); }
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b" class="tomato">b
  <div id="b1">b1</div>
  <div id="b2" class="hello">b2 (class hello)</div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="banana">Banana</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="c">Click to remove b</div>
```

Comment: In some cases @Andreas, `for (n of m.addedNodes) { if (n.matches(selector)) ... n.querySelectorAll` generate errors like `TypeError: n.querySelectorAll is not a function`, is there a cleaner way than doing manually `if (n.matches && n.matches(selector))` and `if (n.querySelectorAll)`?

Comment: Skip `#TextNode`s -> `.nodeType`